# ExtJs open a view from the same view

Tags: extjs

I am opening a view using the following code

```
var reader = Ext.create('Ext.view.ReaderWindow', {});
reader.show();
```

Inside the ReaderWindow view on clicking an a tag element,i am opening the same view (using the code above) again but with different content.

Once i close the  ReaderWindow which i opened second. I could not able to see the ReaderWindow which i opened first.

My question is how to use the same view twice. In other words how to open the same view from the view itself.

```
Ext.define('Ext.view.ReaderWindow', {
extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
alias: 'widget.reader',

id: 0,
file_path: '',
file_title: '',
file_type: '',
id: 'reader',
itemId: 'reader',
maxHeight: 800,
maxWidth: 900,
minHeight: 300,
minWidth: 500,
layout: {
type: 'anchor'
},
title: 'File Reader',
modal: true,

initComponent: function() {
var me = this;

Ext.applyIf(me, {
items: [
{
xtype: 'form',
anchor: '100% 100%',
id: 'reader_form',
itemId: 'reader_form',
maxHeight: 800,
maxWidth: 900,
minHeight: 300,
minWidth: 500,
autoScroll: true,
bodyPadding: 10,
items: [
{
xtype: 'displayfield',
anchor: '100%',
id: 'file_contents',
itemId: 'file_contents',
maxWidth: 900,
minWidth: 50,
hideLabel: true,
name: 'file_contents'
}
]
}
],
dockedItems: [
{
xtype: 'toolbar',
anchor: '100% 5%',
dock: 'bottom',
id: 'reader_toolbar',
itemId: 'reader_toolbar',
items: [
{
xtype: 'tbfill'
},
{
xtype: 'button',
handler: function(button, event) {
me.destroy();
},
id: 'close_btn',
itemId: 'close_btn',
text: 'Close',
tooltip: 'Close the file reader window.'
}
]
}
],
listeners: {
beforerender: {
fn: me.reader_windowBeforeRender,
scope: me
}
}
});

me.callParent(arguments);
},

reader_windowBeforeRender: function(component, eOpts) {

this.setTitle(this.file_title + ' for ID ' + this.id);

this.setFormTitle(this.file_path);




Ext.model.FileReaderModel.load(this.id, {
params: {
'file':        this.file_path,
'file_type': this.file_type
},
success: function(file_reader) {

var contents_field = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('[name=file_contents]')[0];

var contents = file_reader.get('file_contents');
var pattern = /(\/.*?\.\S*)/gi;
contents = contents.replace(pattern, "<a href='#' class='samplefile'>$1</a>");

contents_field.setValue('<pre>' + contents + '</pre>');

Ext.select('.samplefile').on('click', function() {
var sample_file_path = this.innerHTML;

var Id = this.id;

var reader = Ext.create('Ext.view.ReaderWindow', {
id: Id,
file_path: sample_file_path,
file_title: 'Sample File',
file_type:  'output'
});

reader.show();

});
},
failure: function(file_reader, response) {
}
});



},

setFormTitle: function(file_path) {
var form_panel = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#reader_form');
form_panel[0].setTitle('File is: ' + file_path);

}

});
```

Comment: It will help if you post the code from `Ext.view.ReaderWindow` because you may have something "static" in your class declaration that's getting destroyed when the second instance is closed.  In other words, the two instances are actually sharing an object you don't expect them to be sharing.

Comment: Your `Ext.view.ReaderWindow` sounds like an extension of `Ext.window.Window` and not `Ext.view.View`, so I'm guessing that you might need `closeAction: 'hide'`, but that's a little bit of a leap, seeing as you're creating a new instance... but like Joe Holloway said, it's hard to tell without more code.

Comment: Even before closing the second window. The first window in the background seems to have only the layout shape and no content inside it.

Comment: Another thing i noticed is..The first window as only the layout and also there is another small div outer to the layout which has the id of the window which is "reader"

Comment: An the first window layout which seems to have no content has id ext-gen

Comment: Per the StackOverflow Q&A format, I'd recommend solving your show/hide problem first and then asking questions about layout in a separate question thread.  You'll have better luck getting answers the less noisy the questions are.

Comment: I was trying to give more information to solve the show/hide problem.So that you can get a feel what happens for the first window. But will make sure next time to stick with one thing. Thanks your answer worked for me!

Comment: No worries, I didn't realize you were thinking they were related problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One big problem I see is that you are giving some of your components a non-unique `id` property.  When an `id` is specified, ExtJS uses it as the ID of the underlying DOM element instead of generating a unique one.  This is almost certainly not what you want on a reusable component given that IDs need to be unique within the DOM.

Even if you are generating a unique `id` when you construct the top-level Window object, its child components (`reader_form`, `file_contents`, etc) are not getting a unique `id`.

In other words, when your second window is shown, you now have multiple DOM elements with the same ID and that breaks the DOM. In my ExtJS application, I've yet to find a valid use case for overriding the `id` property, but that doesn't mean there isn't one.  It would most likely be for global scaffolding elements or something where your application guarantees only one instance of a particular component will ever be instantiated.

You **can** use `itemId` because that's an ExtJS construct that doesn't get translated into the DOM.  It gives you similar features to having an ID on a DOM element, except that it behaves more intuitively in the context of the ExtJS component hierarchy and selector APIs.

My recommendation is to remove the `id` property from your components and let ExtJS generate unique ones for you and leverage `itemId` only where you absolutely must have a known identifier on your component.

Comment: Thanks removing the id and using itemid when getting the element worked.  Thanks a lot.